# SSL "Peer not Authenticated" error with HttpClient 4 - works in some case but not others

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a wildcard cert for *.mydomain.com (the names have been changed to protect the innocent...that is NOT the real domain :) )

When using a correctly implemented Java HttpClient 4 (the issue is not seen in FF), Service calls made via HTTPS to api.mydomain.com are successful where as identical service calls made to non-production subdomains of mydomain.com (developer.mydomain.com, api-beta.mydomain.com, api-uat.mydomain.com) generate this Exception with the Test harness code below:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
at com.mydomain.httpclientexample.HttpClientTestv2.main(HttpClientTestv2.java:54)
```

While the SLL cert on developer.mydomain.com, api-beta.mydomain.com & api-uat.mydomain.com appears to be the same WC cert as api.mydomain.com, the exception is not seen on api.mydomain.com but it is on the other sub-domains. The code works on api-na.mydomain.com and should work on the non-production subdomains.

Any ideas?

Client code:  As you can see, I can easily change the ADDRESS_VALIDATION_SERVICE_URI I want to call.  The api.mydomain.com one works without the SSLPeerUnverifiedException;  the other three URIs throw the exception...

```
package com.mydomain.httpclientexample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HttpClientTestv2 {

//public final static String ADDRESS_VALIDATION_SERVICE_URI = "https://developer.mydomain.com/v1.0/stores/MYSTORE/address/validate.xml";
public final static String ADDRESS_VALIDATION_SERVICE_URI = "https://api-beta.mydomain.com/v1.0/stores/MYSTORE/address/validate.xml";
//public final static String ADDRESS_VALIDATION_SERVICE_URI = "https://api-uat.mydomain.com/v1.0/stores/MYSTORE/address/validate.xml";
//public final static String ADDRESS_VALIDATION_SERVICE_URI = "https://api.mydomain.com/v1.0/stores/MYSTORE/address/validate.xml";
public final static String APIKEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "apikey";
public final static String APIKEY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = "2c90bc83e821364ffa557486c3e2a44e";


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ADDRESS_VALIDATION_SERVICE_URI);
    System.out.println("executing request" + httpPost.getRequestLine());  

    //set a request header 
    httpPost.setHeader(APIKEY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME , APIKEY_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE);

    //add the xml body   
    StringEntity postBody = null;
    try {
        postBody = new StringEntity(getXMLDoc(),"UTF-8"); 
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Exception Caught in UnsupportedEncodingException catch block");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        uee.printStackTrace();
    }   

    httpPost.setEntity(postBody);


    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");  
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());  

        if (entity != null) {  
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
            System.out.println("Content:" + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            //          entity.consumeContent();  
        }  


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Exception Caught in ClientProtocolException catch block");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Exception Caught in ClientProtocolException catch block");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

    // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,   
    // shut down the connection manager to ensure  
    // immediate deallocation of all system resources  
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();          

}





private static String getXMLDoc() {

    StringBuffer XMLDoc = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><AddressValidationRequest xmlns=\"http://api.mydomain.com/schema/checkout/1.0\">") 
    .append("<Header><MaxAddressSuggestions>5</MaxAddressSuggestions></Header>") 
    .append("<Address><Line1>17243 S. Mill Ln</Line1><Line2/><City>Ocean View</City><MainDivision>DE</MainDivision><CountryCode>US</CountryCode><PostalCode>19970</PostalCode></Address>") 
    .append("</AddressValidationRequest>"); 

    return XMLDoc.toString();

}



}
```